# Varargs in Java

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list, variadic-functions

So I created a ListNode.java class and was playing around with varargs. I defined the constructor ListNode(int... values) so that it'll make a Linked List with its next references defined depending on what you passed in. For example,

`ListNode head = new ListNode(1, 2, 3); // is equivalent to 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null`

I was testing what will happen when I pass in nothing, i.e. `new ListNode()` and such a call will result in

`ListNode emptyHead = new ListNode(); // is equivalent to 0 -> null`

Can you explain why? Below is my implementation of ListNode.java.

```
public class ListNode {
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;

    public ListNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public ListNode(int... values) {
        if (values.length == 0) return;

        this.val = values[0];
        this.next = null;
        ListNode ptr = this;
        for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            ptr.next = new ListNode(values[i]);
            ptr = ptr.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can you explain why?" Because you're passing in zero values, so it's a zero-length array. Can you explain what you expected otherwise?

Comment: BTW: it's almost certainly not a good idea to have these two constructors. Remove the `ListNode(int)` constructor, just let the other one handle the 1-element case.

Comment: when you say 'new ListNode();' you created 1 object and because of default int val 0 and pointer value null, you recived 0 -> null

Comment: you val is a primitive type, hence gets initialised to default value which is 0. If you were using Object such as String, it would be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you pass nothing to the constructor, it received an empty array.

Your `if (values.length == 0) return;` statement causes the constructor execution to end.

Therefore `this.val` remains `0` by default and `this.next` remains `null`.